Unreal Engine texture distortion
I am having problems with my mesh respectively with texture in UE5.
This is how the texture looks like in Substance:
Substance preview
And this is how it looks in UE5
UE5 Preview
Do you know any solution to this problem?
I have tried the Use Full Precision UVs but it didn’t help. It should look like in Substance Painter but it doesn't
Thank you

It looks exactly like low precision of UVs, maybe the setting is somewhere ignored or overwritten

I am not really good at UE5 but if the textures is weirdly displayed on an object isn't it because of the object proportions ?

@AlexeyS.Larionov it seems like it, but where else could it be set up?

Do you see this in the editor, or the built game? Is the game built for mobile?
